# Changing game size in Phaser dynamically

Tags: resize, size, scaling, phaser-framework, states

I'm building a game in which I can enter a building, which I'm handling via states. In other words, when my character overlaps with the door, the program starts a new state in which the interior of the building is built. Now, I want the interior to have smaller dimensions than the world, so I want to change the game size when I start this new state.

I tried this:

```
create: function()
{
  //game size was 1000x700, I want to scale it to 700x450
  game.width = 700;
  game.height = 450;

  //rest of creation code...
}
```

I also tried things like changing camera bounds, world bounds, world size, but method above shows the most promise.

The problem, however, is that the resize for some reason does not show until I click away from my browser tab and back. Calling game.width in the console yields 700 at all times, but it doesn't show it as such until tabbing out and back.

On top of that, the contents of the game (floor, furniture) are scaled down when the game resizes, defeating the purpose. I don't understand why it would, since there's no scaling anywhere in my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Edit:
I just saw that you were the one asking the question I linked to, so I guess the question is solved :D

---

I had a similar problem some time ago. As you described yourself: what you are doing is a resize! So the game resizes itself which means the same as re-scaling everything in the game.
if you want to cut the game smaller you can simply use

```
game.scale.setGameSize(700, 450);.
```

(see [this](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/17437-changing-game-size-dynamically/?hl=%2Bchange%20%2Bworld%20%2Bsize) post if you need more information)

As additional information: I later had problems with cutting the game size equally on all sides, so if you should come to face the same problem, have a look at [this](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/18706-resizing-world-calculated-from-center/) post